# Argument Error: The scope body needs to be callable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, argument-error

I'm working through the 'Ruby On Rails 3 Essential Training' and have received a problem when using name scopes.  When finding records and using queries withing the Rails console everything went smoothly until I tried to use a name scope in my subject.rb file. This is my code in the subject.rb file.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    
  scope :visible, where(:visible => true)

end
```

I saved the .rb file and restarted my Rails console but when I run from my rails console:

```
subjects = Subject.visible
```

I get: `ArgumentError: The scope body needs to be callable.`

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The scope's body needs to be wrapped in something callable like a Proc or Lambda:

```
scope :visible, -> {
  where(:visible => true)
}
```

The reason for this is that it ensures the contents of the block is evaluated each time the scope is used.

Comment: Okay this makes sense and I can't wait to try it tomorrow morning so I can continue learning. Thanks for the quick response.  Any guesses to why the instructor didn't use any wrapping in his example.  It seemed to work with him. I also noticed that the newest version of ruby doesn't use the: "self.up" "self.down" labeling. The instructor said ruby doesn't need that in the newer versions but I had to include it in order to make migrations work.  It's gets confusing when there are different versions of rails, since the training videos were made.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SamGruse this is the Rails 4 way of doing it, the course seems to use Rails 3

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error , while before my solution I had a space between `where` and `(` like below

```
scope :registered , -> { where ( place_id:  :place_id , is_registered: :true ) }
```

after i removed the space between `where` and `(` like below i made my page working

```
scope :registered , -> { where( place_id:  :place_id , is_registered: :true ) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed, this is rails 4 way of calling scopes. You'd need to change it, if you're upgrading to Rails 4 from Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using: `scope :visible, where(:visible => true)` goes for eager loading, and has been deprecated in Rails 4.

```
scope :visible, where(:visible => true)
```

This line of code gets evaluated when the particular class is loaded, and *not at the time, this very `scope` is called*.

There are a few cases when this thing does matter, like:

```
scope :future, where('published_at > ?', Time.now)
scope :future, -> { where('published_at > ?', Time.now) }
```

In first case, `?` will be replaced with the very time the class would have been loaded, but the second & correct case, that time will be used at which the scope would have been called on the class.