# Scope with joins in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, named-scope, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've got code similar to

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  scope :with_comments, joins(:comments)
end
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082147/38765), but when I use it in Rails 4.2, I get

```
/Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:143:in `scope': The scope body needs to be callable. (ArgumentError)
```

Have the rules with regards to allowing joins in scope changed between Rails 4 and Rails 4.2? I can see mention of joins in the [4.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html), but I can't tell if it's applicable here.

Comment: Try `scope :with_comments, -> { joins(:comments) }`

Comment: this is change in Rails 4. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The scope body needs to be callable. (ArgumentError)

This should work

```
scope :with_comments, -> { joins(:comments) }
```

A nice explanation [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951671/argument-error-the-scope-body-needs-to-be-callable)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try it like this ?

```
scope :with_comments, -> { joins(:comments)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You should do as follows:

`scope :with_comments, -> { joins(:comments) }`

You should have a look at this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)